# how to print 5 Non-consecutive numbers per row?

Tags: python

our teacher asked us to prepare this activity at home:
write a Python code that shows all the numbers between 100 and 999 that the sum of eachone's digits is less than 10. Exp: 121 because 1+2+1= 4 < 10
(You should print every 5 numbers in a row)

I solved the first part but I couldn't finish until the end. In fact, this is my work:

```
for i in range(100, 1000):
    s = i//100+i%100//10+i%10
    if s<10:
        print(i)
```

The problem is that the numbers are not consecutive so how we can organize them in 5 per row???
Please help me the work is for Monday

Comment: You can save the correct numbers to the list, and then print every fifth number from the list. Or you need it to be done in one loop?

Comment: When posting questions about homework be sure to read the communbity guidelines: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: No I must adhere to the instruction. I cannot use the list of numbers because I shouldn't know them in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [num for num in range(100,1000) if sum(int(n) for n in str(num)) < 10]
print(*(arr[a-5:a] for a in range(5,len(arr),5)), sep="\n")
```

or

```
def ret_sum(n):
    tmp = 0
    for i in str(n):
        tmp += int(i)
    return True if tmp < 10 else False

flag = 0
for num in range(100, 1000):
    if ret_sum(num):
        print(num, end=" ")
        flag += 1
    if flag == 5:
        flag = 0
        print()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is done. But we havn't seen this code yet in class so is there any other more simple solution?